# Identifying new records added for specific date range in same table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with the following table (dummy data included below; Also actual table has about 50K records)

**Table All_Users**

```
ID, Domain, ReportDate, SamAccountName
1, Win1, 1/7/2013, user1
2, Win1, 1/7/2013, user2
3, Win1, 1/7/2013, user3
4, Win1, 1/14/2013, user1
5, Win1, 1/14/2013, user2
6, Win1, 1/14/2013, user3
7, Win1, 1/21/2013, user1
8, Win1, 1/21/2013, user2
9, Win1, 1/21/2013, user3
10, Win1, 1/21/2013, user4
11, Win1, 1/21/2013, user5
```

Every week, we get an extract from AD which we upload to a SQL Server database (identified by the Report date column). **The goal is to be able to run a query to identify new AD accounts added for specific date ranges**.

```
E.g, identify new AD accounts added from 1/7/2013 through 1/21/2013 

The result should be: 
10, Win1, 1/21/2013, user4
11, Win1, 1/21/2013, user5
```

Currently i have a query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ReportDate, SamAccountName, Domain, ID
FROM dbo.tbl_All_Users
WHERE (NOT (SamAccountName IN
       (SELECT SamAccountName
        FROM tbl_All_Users
        WHERE (ReportDate = '1/7/2013')))) AND (ReportDate = '1/21/2013')
```

This was working initially, but as the table grew- the query has started to time out (for obvious reasons- it's not efficient one bit).

What is an efficient way to do this? i have tried using inner joins (as i saw on a posting on this site), but i can't seem to get it to fit my specific case. And given my lack of SQL knowledge, i just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're maybe adding the full extract to the table on each weekly import, and then trying to find records that are unique for the last import. If that is correct, would it maybe work better to not import the duplicate records in the first place? If not, as others have mentioned, indexes on the report date and account name columns could probably greatly improve your performance, if they already exist, make sure they're not fragmented.

Comment: Yes, we add the full extract each time. This is part of our audit/compliance process to keep track of the status of the account-when an account was enabled, disabled, expired, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Before you rewrite your query, you should look at the use of indexes.  Do you have indexes on the table?  If not, you might start with an index on the ReportDate column.

You'll probably get great improvement with that index, but then you may have more opportunities with more advanced performance analysis.

Comment: i'll look into this. I think the indexes were setup but i will have to double check to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SamAccountName, MIN(ReportDate)                    
FROM tbl_All_Users 
GROUP BY SamAccountName
HAVING MIN(ReportDate) BETWEEN '1/7/2013' AND '1/21/2013'
```

Comment: i'll run this to see if this is providing what i need.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at the query plan and see where the greatest costs are, it may also suggest new indexes that could improve that specific query. The database tuning advisor will go a step further and also suggest additional stats. Just be aware that additional indexes generally increase the cost of inserts and updates.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not exactly clear - do you want to return all users except for added on these 2 range dates (as your query seem to be doing)?

In this case:

```
;with newlyAdded (select SamAccountName from dbo.tbl_Al_Users
 where ReportDate IN ('2012017', '20130121'))

 select distinct ReportDate, SamAccountName, Domain, ID
 from dbo.tbl_All_Users T
 where not exists (select 1 from newlyAdded nA where nA.SamAccountName = T.SamAccountName)
```

Comment: I want to return only the added users..i.e., out put the delta between the 2 reports (or range dates).

Comment: no worries. the indexes helped. i should be good to go for now.